# Map post parameters to DTO in request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8

In my `Spring` boot application, I'm sending the `POST` data with the following (e.g) params:

```
data: {
        'title': 'title',
        'tags': [ 'one', 'two' ],
        'latitude': 20,
        'longitude': 20,
        'files': [ ], // this comes from a file input and shall be handled as multipart file
    }
```

In my `@Controller` I have:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/new/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = BaseController.MIME_JSON, consumes = BaseController.MIME_JSON
)
public @ResponseBody HttpResponse performSpotUpload(final SpotDTO spot) {
// ...
}
```

where `SpotDTO` is a non-`POJO` class with all `getters` and `setters`.

```
public class SpotDTO implements DataTransferObject {

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("tags")
    private String[] tags;

    @JsonProperty("latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @JsonProperty("longitude")
    private double longitude;

    @JsonProperty("files")
    private MultipartFile[] multipartFiles;

    // all getters and setters
}
```

Unfortunately all fields are `null` when I receive the request. Spring is unable to map the parameters to my `DTO` object.

I guess I'm missing some configuration but I do not know which one.

---

Other similar questions are resolved by just setting fields accessors on the `DTO` class. This does not work for me.

Also I have noticed that if I specify each parameter in the method:

```
@RequestParam("title") final String title,
```

the method is not even reached by the request. I can see the incoming request in a `LoggingInterceptor` `preHandle` method, but nothing in `postHandle`. A `404` response is sent back.

Comment: The request object in Chrome Dev Tools have all the required values?

Comment: @ASOlivieri yes, all set (files is an empty array though, but it shouldn't break the controller)

Comment: You should add `@RequestBody` annotation before  `SpotDTO spot`. i.e `@RequestBody SpotDTO spot`

Comment: You controller class should also be annotated with @RestController along with what Hadi J said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're just missing the [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation on your parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/new/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = BaseController.MIME_JSON, consumes = BaseController.MIME_JSON
)
public @ResponseBody HttpResponse performSpotUpload(@RequestBody final SpotDTO spot) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: With the number of times I've forgotten it, I'm conditioned to look for it now.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `@RequestBody` annotation before `SpotDTO spot`. i.e 
`@RequestBody SpotDTO spot`

```
 public @ResponseBody HttpResponse performSpotUpload(@RequestBody SpotDTO spot) {
    // ...
  }
```